# FragmentPagerAdapter issue - my first tab doesn't load its data, but if I tap on the third tab and then back to the first, it loads

Tags: android

I have a FragmentPagerAdapter with three tabs, the first two of which are PostListFragments (code below) and the third which is a different type of fragment with no data loading going on.

The first PostListFragment in tab 1 doesn't finish loading its data, but if I go to tab 3 (specifically the third, doesn't work for tab 2) and then back to tab 1, it loads its data.

The second tab seems to load fine. Is there something going on with the first tab being inserted into the ViewPager that interrupts its loading?

[Gist for PostListFragment](https://gist.github.com/tbarsbay/03b2a62b23e73725b291)

[Gist for FragmentPagerAdapter](https://gist.github.com/tbarsbay/09f6b27410e62a4201fc)

Update: Currently the two PostListFragments are in positions 0 and 1 in the ViewPager. When I make it so that they're in positions 0 and 2 (with the non-data-loading tab in the middle), everything works fine. Is it something with loading two of the same class of PostListFragment at once (since ViewPager loads position 0 and 1 at the same time) that's making their presenter or something send the data to the wrong fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you use dagger and inject presenter class I'm assuming that your list fragments holds the very same instance of `PostListPresenter`. (your presenter is a singleton or scoped `PerAcitivity` singleton)

So when you have same fragment class in position 0 and 1 they are created at the same time and presenter class will populate fragment which last called `setView()` method.

When you have them on position 0 and 2, `setView()` is called seperatly so everything seems to work fine.

If this is the case you should consider creating per fragment components with PerFragment scoped singletons. Then all your PostListFragments will have unique instances of PostListPresenter.

Hope that helped

I would do something like this:

1. Create sope for Fragments

   @Scope
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   public @interface PerFragment {
   }
2. Create base FragmentComponent and Module

Component:

```
@PerFragment
@Component(
    dependencies = ActivityComponent.class,
    modules = FragmentModule.class
)
public interface FragmentComponent {
    Fragment fragment();
}
```

Module:

```
@Module
public class FragmentModule {
    private final Fragment fragment;

    public FragmentModule(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerFragment
    Fragment provideFragment(){
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

3. Create Component and Module for specific Fragment

Component:

```
@PerFragment
@Component(
    dependencies = ActivityComponent.class,
    modules = {
        FragmentModule.class,
        MyModule.class
    }
)
public interface MyComponent extends FragmentComponent {
    void inject(MyFragment fragment);
}
```

Module:

```
@Module
public class MyModule {

    @Provides
    @PerFragment
    MyPresenter provideMtPresenter() {
        return new MyPresenterImpl();
    }
}
```

4. Make getter in Activity (which contains MyFragment) for its component
5. In BaseFragment class create BaseFragmentModule instance and getter for it
6. In MyFragment create MyComponent instance and inject it

   MyComponent component = DaggerMyComponent.builder()
               .activityComponent(((BaseActivity)activity).getComponent())
               .fragmentModule(getFragmentModule())
               .myModule(new MyModule())
               .build();

   component.inject(this);

Comment: This is what I felt was happening. So currently my PerActivity is defined as:
'@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

public @interface PerActivity {}'

How would I define PerFragment / what RetentionPolicy would I use?

Comment: PerFragment is essentially the same, then you have to annotate your BaseFragmentComponent and all provided instances in you fragment modules.

Comment: I can update my answet with some sample code if you want to.

Comment: That would be really great. I'm very new to Dagger and D.I. and don't fully understand scoping and components/modules that well yet.

Comment: Could I still check it out? Perhaps to see some good practices with Dagger?

Comment: What you posted is almost exactly what I did - thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. You can always upvote my answer to give me more points :)

Comment: I did but I don't have 15 reputation yet so I think it doesn't appear publicly :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your adapter extend [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) instead of FragmentStateAdapter.

Comment: I tried that earlier and it didn't work unfortunately.